# How to access ElasticSearch domain endpoint URL in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have created elasticsearch domain in AWS and integrated with cloudwatch logs which eventually sends logs to elasticsearch cluster with help of lambda function. It has got successfully created and it gives me one endpoint URL, something like this `https://search-elkprod-c63hwtlyqgdogkw55w6osdfzwu.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com'.

When i click this link i get this message :

```
{
  "name" : "S7hluCW",
  "cluster_name" : "567294256180:elkprod",
  "cluster_uuid" : "4UdCvJT9R4-H05MSXqg9tQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.4",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "d2ef93d",
    "build_date" : "2019-04-08T13:15:27.206923Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now my questions are:

- How to access this cluster? I want to check whether my logs are going to the 
  cluster or not.
- If this is a cluster, where are the instances that would have been launched with this cluster?

Please help me on this. Please let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: You are accessing to the cluster. If you want to request the cluster, try to do some request with curl, or access kibana, which is normally created with the cluster (go to the elasticsearch console in aws to find kibana url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your two questions.

1. You can use Kibana which is a popular visualization tool. This will help you to see the total number of indexes created. With this you can add the graphs to tell the number of indexes added in the past 1hr,1day, 1week ..etc

To Access Kibana you can use the URL **elasticsearch-domain-endpoint/_plugin/kibana/**

2. AWS will take care of managing infrastructure for elastic search. Thus in case the increase in load or storage, you can manage with a single click or with an API.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question, "If this is a cluster, where are the instances that would have been launched with this cluster?":

This instances are created and managed by AWS so you dont have direct access to them (you cant SSH to them or anything). The only way for you to interact with them is through endpoint and services that can use that endpoint (kibana, curl, cerebro...)